# Why can't implement the interface this way

Tags: c#

I need to add a variable to the signature of the `SendAsync` method but when I try to do that I get an error that I need implement interface that matches the `SendAsync` without the new variable.

Can I have both? I guess I'm trying to overload an interface.

Code below.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService 
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message, string OAEmailAddress)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message, OAEmailAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add *another* method.

Comment: if you can able to do that without defining method in interface , then what is use of interface , please suggestion to check you knowledge of interface

Comment: I hate when people down vote and don't explain why, but my guess is because your question was so simple, you could have answered it yourself with a few min of research or even just a simple test or two with the code.

Comment: Your getting downvoted because of fatigue with answering questions that have been asked repeatedly.  Your question is really just you learning the fundamentals of coding, and the "experts" tend to get a little jaded after awhile.  The answers below should set you on the right course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is a **contract you have to fullfill *exactly***. In particular how should a client know when to use two and when to use only a single parameter? Imagine you´d have an interface `IMyInterface` whose only method `DoSomething` doesn´t have any parameters:

```
IMyInterface instance = getInstance();
instance.DoSomething();
```

No you have a class implementing that interface:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void DoSomething(string arg1, string arg2) { ... }
}
```

Here all you know is that `instance` is of type `IMyInterface` whose `DoSomething`-method doesn´t expect *anything*. How should a user of your interface know that the *actual* type (in this case `MyClass`) however needs more parameters to call the method? In fact he does not even know that `getInstance` even returned an instance of type `MyClass`, it could have been also any other class that implements the interface.

That´s why interfaces exist: **they clearly state what you can do with an instance and how to do it**. Everything beyond this needs some extension to that interface, e.g. by using another method within that interface, or by extending the interface with a second interface.

Answer (score 1):

The interface is a specification that means any implementation MUST provide at least those functions specified.   You are free to implement more functions that those specified.

Answer (score 1):

This method exists in the interface, and the declaration ("signature") must match between the class an the interface, so there are only a few options:

- Add the parameter both in the class and in the interface (and everywhere where you use that interface),
- Make a second method in the class. That can be an overload or a method with a different name.

If you add a method, it doesn't *have* to be exposed through an interface. If you need it, and it makes sense to you, you can add the second method to the same interface, or to a different interface (a class can implement multiple interfaces), or to no interface at all.